# AngularJS Animate DIV from bottom to top on page load- Slideup

Tags: angularjs

In my current project I need to implement slide up functionality for my main content `div` during the page load i.e,. similar to jQuery animate.

I want to implement this using a `directive` to keep the code clean instead of putting it in controller. I'm able to achieve it using the below code through jQuery, but this is not working when integrated with AngularJS. Any help is much appreciated.

Css:

```
.cont-gall{
    overflow:scroll;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    top: 850px;
    padding:0 0 280px 0px;
    position: relative; 
    height:700px;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

I'm applying this jQuery in the `document.ready()`, it works fine when the page content is static, but when I apply the AngularJs to load the content it doesn't.

```
$('.cont-gall').animate({'top': '50px'}, 3500);
```

Comment: after this code. add if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply().This helps you to run the digest cycle

Comment: this should be done by pure css

Comment: you can take help and from my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yor are not doing right if you are doing in jquery way:

**Doing it in angulars prospective**

You can make an `directive` that you can use in DOM/html  in that directive you can `initially` provide an class that will set transition time and style to the element and in `linking` phase you can apply the `transition changes class`

```
 <cont class="myDiv">abcd</cont>
```

For animation you can use css3 transition

```
.myDiv{

    position:absolute;
   -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    /*to only change opacity*/
    /*-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear*/
   -moz-transition: 1s linear;
   -o-transition: 1s linear;
   transition: 1s linear;


}

.animateTop{

    top:10px;
}
```

Directive

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('cont', function () {       

    return {
      restrict:"E",

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   
        element.addClass('animateTop');
            $compile(element)(scope);


        }
}
});
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('cont', function () {       
  
    return {
      restrict:"E",
     //template:"<div class='myDiv'>aa</div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   
          element.addClass('animateTop');
            $compile(element)(scope);
         }
    }
});
```

```css
.myDiv{
  display:block;
    width:200px;
  color:black;
  background:red;
    position:absolute;
   -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    /*to only change opacity*/
    /*-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear*/
   -moz-transition: 1s linear;
   -o-transition: 1s linear;
   transition: 1s linear;


}

.animateTop{
 background:pink;
    top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<cont class="myDiv">abcd</cont>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple directive for that:

```
angular.module('demoApp').directive('animatedToTop', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).animate({
        'top': '50px'
      }, 3500);
    }
  }
});
```

In the view:

```
<div class="cont-gall" animated-to-top></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but by removing the $ in front of the element.